# modifying a pointer that points to another pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Using no other objects besides those already declared, how can
you alter ptrptr so that it points at a pointer to b without
directly touching ptr ?

```
int a,b;
int *ptr;
int**ptrptr;

ptr =&a;
ptrptr=&ptr;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:array], [tag:vector] or [tag:resize]?  Please reduce your tags to just those that describe the problem you are having.

Comment: ops .. sry mate ,i was about to ask something but i have figured it on my own so i deleted it and forgot to remove the tages .. thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to touch directly ptr.  So  `ptr = &b;` is not an option.

But this doesn't prevent changing it indirectly.  So   `*ptrptr=&b;` would be the way to go.

Comment: That is not actually altering (changing) `ptrptr`.   It is changing `*ptrptr` so it points to `b` (i.e. contains the address of `b`), which is a somewhat different from the question asked.

Comment: I think it is the exact answer to this question. How to work with pointers to pointer?

Comment: i got the question from a book called Data structure and problem solving by mark Allen .. isnt changing the address normally changes the value assigned to it ?

Comment: @ahmedelbarky Suppose `a=1;` and `b=2;`. None of these pointer statements change the value contained in `a` or in `b`.  It only changes the pointers themselves.  If you print `**ptrptr` immediately after your code, you'd get `1`.  If you print `**ptrptr` after my statement, you'd get `2`.  But `a` and `b` are still unchanged.  If after my statement you'd assign `**ptrptr=3;` then only the content of `b` would be changed to `3`.